# Filter to exclude elements from array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Trying to filter some entries from an array. It's not guaranteed they are in the master array, so I'm testing through an iteration.

```
total = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']
hide = ['charlie', 'echo']

pick = []
for i in total
  if !hide.include?(i)
    puts i
    pick.push(i)
  end
end
puts pick
```

This isn't working. Is there a better way of providing this kind of filter?

Comment: what do you mean not working?  seems okay to me...what is your expected response?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ruby lets you use public instance methods on two arrays to get their intersecting or exclusive elements:

```
a1 = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']
a2 = ['charlie', 'echo']
puts a1 - a2
=>  ['alpha', 'bravo', 'delta']

puts a1 & a2
=>  ['charlie', 'echo']
```

For more information check [rubydoc Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html). It's likely that you'll find exactly what you need there.

Comment: OK I had no clue you could do that.  THAT is a helpful method.  I come from a language where you pretty much have to write your own.  Nicely done.  Thank you.

Comment: Later date:  Just to add, with Ruby 2.6, there are new methods that provide much better access to intersections and the like, in arrays.  Happy Days.

Answer (score 46):

## Array#excluding (Rails 6+)

If you are using Rails (or a standalone ActiveSupport), starting from version 6, there is a [Array#excluding](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-excluding) method which returns a copy of the array excluding the specified elements.

```
["David", "Rafael", "Aaron", "Todd"].excluding("Aaron", "Todd") # => ["David", "Rafael"]
[ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ] ].excluding([ [ 1, 0 ] ]) # => [ [ 0, 1 ] ]
```

So, your example can be rewritten as follows:

```rb
total = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']
hide = ['charlie', 'echo']

pick = total.excluding(hide)
# => ['alpha', 'bravo', 'delta']
```

Answer (score 13):

How about `.select`/`reject`? Or the mutating version `.select!`/`reject!`?

Here are the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select).

Usage:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3].select { |x| x > 1 }
# output: [2, 3]
```

Or in your case:

```
excluded = [0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3].reject { |x| excluded.include?(x) }
# output: [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 11):

Your code works for me.
As for "better way", you could use [`Array#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
total = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']
hide = ['charlie', 'echo']

pick = total.reject do |i|
  hide.include?(i)
end
puts pick
```

Not only it is more idiomatic, but Ruby's `for i in collection` loops are implemented in terms of `collection.each { |i| }`. A method with a block is almost always a better alternative.

Comment: I'm new to Ruby.  How would you paraphrase that block then?  I have always seen these blocks as iterators instead of how it's presented here.

Comment: @Rich_F 'reject' is key here, looking at the docs, you'll see that you can pass a block to reject and that it will return a "new" list.

Comment: @TheF Yes, that part I get.  I was just intrigued about the idiomatic point, because it's registered differently in my head.  "Reject those in this array of which match those in 'hide'".  The paraphrasing is what I'm interested in.  Can you paraphrase all this with the word "do" in it so it's clear?  I have been using blocks for quite some time now, but the 'do' is a confusing item.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `do` is just a Ruby keyword to open a block. You can use `do - end` or `{ }`, with the former more idiomatic for multi-line blocks, and the latter generally used for one-liners.

Comment: If you just want a human friendly explanation, then you should look at the docs. They put it quite cleanly: "Returns a new array containing the items in self for which the given block is not true". You should get familiar with the terminology and style used in the the docs, as they're quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Inject method in class Array if version rails < 6.

```rb
class Array
 def excluding(array = [])
  self - array
 end
end
```

Comment: No Rails, just core Ruby.