# Get a substring that is present in two strings

Tags: ruby, string

I have

```
"abcdeg"
```

and

```
"uytbaf"
```

What is the most efficient way to get `"ab"`, which is common in both strings?

Comment: Why is the output not `"abf"` or simply `"f"`?

Comment: here I want `ab ` which is also match `ba ` => by sort `ab`

Comment: `"ab"` != `"ba"` - How are you trying to match the substring?

Comment: "here I want" - that's an example, not a rule. it's impossible to generalize it (that's without adding some arbitrary rule).

Comment: yes I know "ab" != "ba" but `["a", "b"] == ["b","a"].sort`

Comment: What happens if you include `c` in the second string, near `ba`? If I have `"bca".split.sort` is that expected to match too?

Comment: edited my question for easy to understand now

Comment: `"ab"` is neither a [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) nor a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of `"uytbaf"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make lists from your strings using [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chars), and then use operators like `+`, `-` or `&` to get their intersection for example.

```
("abcdef".chars & "uytbaf".chars).join
# => "abf"
```

For more information, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436091/filter-to-exclude-elements-from-array/32436226#32436226) I gave.

Comment: I think the poster is looking for the longest common substring, not for the common characters.

Comment: Ah, I have overseen that. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: perfect @eugen u r my boss